# Get class's method return outside of class itself

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Python, so please give possibly detailed explanation.
So, I have code where I post form via ajax on /query an then obtain data on server to return for displaying on template /search:

views.py

```
class SomeClass(View):

     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       if request.method =='POST':
        data = request.body
        qd = QueryDict(data)
        place = qd.values()[2]
        indate = qd.values()[3]
        outdate = qd.values()[0]
        url = ('http://)
        req = requests.get(url).text
        json_data = json.loads(req)
        self.results = []
        for result in json_data.get('hotelList'):
            self.results.append(result)

     return HttpResponse(self.results)


def function(request):

    var = SomeClass()
    v = var.results

    return render(request,'search.html', {'v':v})
```

search.html

```
 <body>
  <form id="form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="place">Place</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place" placeholder="Input city name">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="check-in">check-in date</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="check-in"  placeholder="check-in date">
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="check-out">check-out date</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="check-out" placeholder="check-out date">
   </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit- btn">Submit</button>{% csrf_token %}
 </form>
<div id="result">
 {% for result in v %}
   {{ result }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
    // posting form using ajaxForm
    $('#submit-btn').click(function(e) {
        var options = {
           type: "POST",
           target:     '#result', // div to update
           url:        '/query/',
            data: {
            place: $("#place").val(),
            check_in: $("#check-in").val(),
            check_out: $("#check-out").val()

            },
           success:    function() {
              alert('');

        }

  </script>
 </body>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('task6_API.views',
   url(r'^search/$', 'search_page', name='search'),
   url(r'^query/$', SomeClass.as_view(), name='search_result'),

)
```

If I just return `self.result`, I get:

```
AttributeError: `'list' object has no attribute 'get'`
```

so I use `HttpResponse`.

I need to receive `results` in my `function`.  How can I get it?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? Are you trying to access a class based view from a function based view? I am pretty sure this is not the correct way to implement what you are after.

Comment: For me no matter  just now whether I access it from function based view or other class. The main thing is how to use return  out of class? Perhaps I am conceptually wrong, so please correct me.

Comment: We can speculate more if you explain what are you trying to accomplish, but your current method is clearly misdirected. To answer your question; `result` is returned by the method `post` and you can theoretically use `v = var.post(request)` to access it. However, `post` method probably needs extra arguments (`*args` or `**kwargs`) to compute the `result`.

Comment: Thank you but if I following you  `v = var.post(request)' I get` 'SomeClass' object has no attribute 'result'`. What else could I do?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `result` instead of `self.result` inside the class?

Comment: excuse me, misunderstood.

Comment: Are `result` and `self.result` suppose to be different? All instance variables in python need to be used in the form `self.attribute` inside the class definition. Also, your error seems to indicate that your `json_data` variable is a list, which doesn't have a `.get` method.

Comment: @user3404344 What do you mean use `result` instead of `self.result` inside the class? One variable would be local to the method and disappear after the method is done executing, the other is bound to the object.

Comment: do you mean `result=[]`? It is just mistake, updated as `self.result[]`. as for second part, yes it is a list, thats why I use HttpResponse to return it.

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko It would help if you posted the full error traceback, but If `json_data` is a list, then `json_data.get` will give you the attribute error.

Comment: @ Zongo, thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example code is not really clear. So I'll attempt to answer, generally, the actual question.

Basically, a class method is just a function that operates on the class instance, passed in as implicit argument usually named "self".

```
class SomeClass:

    def some_method(self, request):
        # do something with request
        return ["I am a str in a list"]

instance = SomeClass()

# Call method on instance. It gets whatever the method returns.

val = instance.some_method(None)

print(val)
```

This produces:

```
['I am a str in a list']
>>>
```

In this case the "self" is not even used, so it could have been just a plain function. This is why you often see plain functions as request handlers. You mostly need classes if you need to retain some state between method calls, and can keep the instance alive between calls.

Comment: Why do you use `some_method(None)`argument ?

Comment: As a placeholder for the `request`, since the example method doesn't actually use it.

Comment: How come? The `post` method checks `request.method` in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the results to the context that you are returning; to do that use `get_context_data`, available from the [`ContextMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin).

To display a template, use the [`TemplateResponseMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#templateresponsemixin).

This completely eliminates the need for your separate view method.

```
class SomeView(View, ContextMixin, TemplateResponseMixin):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(SomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['v'] = self.result
        return ctx

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.result = []
        for data in json_data.get('somedata'):
            self.result.append(data)
```

I really don't see why you are using a class based view here in the first place, your code would be much simpler with:

```
def function(request):
    result = []

    if request.POST:
       json_data = json.loads(request.POST['some_field'])
       result = list(json_data['somedata'])

    return render(request, 'search.html', {'v': result})
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I use `ctx` in my function based view?

Comment: Thank you a very much for your detailed answer but reason why I have divide code to separate views is that I have ajax post for one url  and then I need render page on other url.So I have two different url in my urls.py. How to  make it exactly in my situation?

Comment: I think you should edit your question and explain your problem in detail.